# wordpress - leave out multiple categories in a new wp query

Tags: wordpress

I have a new wordpress query like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat'=>-5, 'paged'=>$paged ) );
```

Now I want to exclude a second category but I can't seem to get the syntax right. I have tried:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat'=>array(-5,-3), 'paged'=>$paged ) );
```

which I thought might work but throws and error and so makes me wonder if 'cat' is the right variable.

and this (which just didn't feel right!)

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'cat'=>-3,-5, 'paged'=>$paged ) );
```

How can I add in a second excluded category please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pre_get_posts` if you want to do it in fucntions.php and in template as answered use category__not_in as argument and reset the query after the loop by `using wp_reset_query();`

Answer (score 1):

add this: 'category__not_in'=>array(5,3)

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'category__not_in'=>array(5,3), 'paged'=>$paged ) );
```